# UIImagePicker on UIPopoverController goes off on click or touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I tried to resize UIImagePickerController on UIPopoverController with following code:

```
 UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                      nil];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
           UIViewController *containerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
            containerController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(360,200);
           [containerController.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
            self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                      initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

             self.popoverController.delegate = self;
            [self.popoverController setPopoverBackgroundViewClass:[PopoverBackgroundView class]];

     [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(512,510,10,10) inView:mC.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:FALSE];
            }
```

imagePicker is populating perfectly as i want,but when i touch the cells of imagePicker inside popover,suddenly it goes off or becomes empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access UIImagePickerController when UIPopoverController will/did dismissed use UIPopoverControllerDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = (UIImagePickerController*)popoverController.contentViewController;
    return YES;
}
```

may help you :)

Comment: ur welcome :)
please can you vote up my answer and accept it as a best answer ;)